# ArrayException in my TestActivity.java class

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, exception

I get ArrayException when i tried run my TestActivity.java class,

This is First Time i use Arrays ,

maybe i did something incorrect

PLEASE HELP AND ANSWER

This is TestActivity.java class :

```
package com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity { 

static String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
static String TrueAnswer ;
static int mark = 0 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button center = (Button) findViewById(R.id.center);
    Button right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
    Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
    TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question) ;

    int number = TestActivity.getNumber();

    question.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number) + " × " + TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(MainActivity.num));

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(4-1) + 1;

    if (i==1){

        TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "center";
        center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
        Random r3 = new Random();
        int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

        right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
        left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

    }else if (i==2){

        TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "right";
        right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
        Random r3 = new Random();
        int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

        center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
        left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

    }else{

        TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "left";
        left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
        Random r3 = new Random();
        int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

        right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
        center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

    }

    center.setOnClickListener(l);
    right.setOnClickListener(l);
    left.setOnClickListener(l);

}

OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (arg0.getTag().toString() == TestActivity.TrueAnswer){
            TestActivity.mark++ ;
        }

        int count = 0 ;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < TestActivity.numbers.length ; i++ ){

            if ( TestActivity.numbers[i] != "" ){
                count = 1 ;
            }

        }

        if (count==0){
            Intent i = new Intent(TestActivity.this,MarkActivity.class) ;
            startActivity(i) ;
            MarkActivity.mark = TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(TestActivity.mark) ;
        }else{

            Button center = (Button) findViewById(R.id.center);
            Button right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
            Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
            TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question) ;

            int number = TestActivity.getNumber();

            question.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number) + " × " + TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(MainActivity.num));

            Random r = new Random();
            int i = r.nextInt(4-1) + 1;

            if (i==1){

                TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "center";
                center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
                Random r2 = new Random();
                int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
                Random r3 = new Random();
                int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

                right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
                left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

            }else if (i==2){

                TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "right";
                right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
                Random r2 = new Random();
                int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
                Random r3 = new Random();
                int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

                center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
                left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

            }else{

                TestActivity.TrueAnswer = "left";
                left.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(number));
                Random r2 = new Random();
                int i2 = r2.nextInt(100-0) + 0;
                Random r3 = new Random();
                int i3 = r3.nextInt(100-0) + 0;

                right.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i2));
                center.setText(TestActivity.ArabicNumbers(i3));

            }
        }

    }
};

public static String ArabicNumbers(int EnglishNumbers){

    char[] ArabicNumbers = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
    String Result = "" ;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < String.valueOf(EnglishNumbers).length() ; i++ ){

        Result += ArabicNumbers[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(EnglishNumbers).substring(i , i + 1))];

    }

    return Result ;

}

public static int getNumber(){
    int[] numbers = {} ;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < TestActivity.numbers.length ; i++ ){
        if(TestActivity.numbers[i] != ""){
            numbers[numbers.length] = Integer.parseInt(TestActivity.numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(numbers.length-0) + 0;

    for( int u = 0 ; u < TestActivity.numbers.length  ; u++  ){

        if ( TestActivity.numbers[u].equals(numbers[i])){
            TestActivity.numbers[u] = "" ;
        }

    }

    return numbers[i] ;
}
}
```

and LogCat :

```
12-20 05:18:55.369: W/dalvikvm(1301): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication/com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication.TestActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication.TestActivity.getNumber(TestActivity.java:180)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:30)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-20 05:18:55.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     ... 11 more
```

Please don't hold my question ,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which statment gives you the exception? any stacktrace?

Comment: Can you post your LogCat?

Comment: Does the program crash on Start on after button click fired?
You should also get a Fatal Exception-81/82 like this on you logCat.

Comment: u r using intent ,so can u just try to remove the static from ur declarations and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try to replace this method becz here you do two mistake here.

public static int getNumber(){
//1.you have gave int array length "numbers" at declaration time.
        int[] numbers = new int[MyActivity.numbers.length] ;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < MyActivity.numbers.length ; i++ ){
            if(!MyActivity.numbers[i].equals("")){
                //2.you have set value of "numbers" array at each index.
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(MyActivity.numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(numbers.length-0) + 0;

        for( int u = 0 ; u < MyActivity.numbers.length  ; u++  ){

            if ( MyActivity.numbers[u].equals(numbers[i])){
                MyActivity.numbers[u] = "" ;
            }

       }

return numbers[i] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You **cannot**  **compare** `String` and `integer` like below code..

```
for( int u = 0 ; u < TestActivity.numbers.length  ; u++  ){

    if ( TestActivity.numbers[u].equals(numbers[i])){
        TestActivity.numbers[u] = "" ;
    }

}
```

You need to compare **like**

```
for( int u = 0 ; u < TestActivity.numbers.length  ; u++  ){

    if ( TestActivity.numbers[u].equals(""+numbers[i])){
        TestActivity.numbers[u] = "" ;
    }

}
```

**or**

```
for( int u = 0 ; u < TestActivity.numbers.length  ; u++  ){

    if ( TestActivity.numbers[u].equals(String.valueOf(numbers[i]))){
        TestActivity.numbers[u] = "" ;
    }

}
```

and also

```
int[] numbers = new int[TestActivity.numbers.length] ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < TestActivity.numbers.length ; i++ ){
    if(TestActivity.numbers[i] != ""){
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(TestActivity.numbers[i]);
    }
}
```